# Trying to download a flash game in .sfw format

Tags: html, flash, download

I tried but couldn't do it.

I tried getting the .sfw file from the source code but the file I got was only 2kb and it did not work. I got a white/gray screen when I launched it. I tried to download the whole website and search for the .sfw file I got the same result. I tried it with chrome and firefox.

I need to launch the .swf file and play it offline. This is my only purpose. Here is the game im trying to get.

http://www.slotozilla.com/free-slots/jackpot-cleopatras-gold

Answer (score 0):

If the game wasn't designed to be played offline, I'd give up.